# Find a lowercase letter surronded by three uppercase letters

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string with a mix of uppercase and lowercase letters. I need want to find every lowercase letter that is surronded by 3 uppercase letters and extract it from the string.

For instance `ZZZaZZZ` I want to extract the `a` in the previous string.

I have written a script that is able to extract `ZZZaZZZ` but not the `a` alone. I know I need to use nested regex expressions to do this but I can not wrap my mind on how to implement this. The following is what I have:

```
import string, re                                                                                                                                                                

if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                                                                                       

    #open the file                                                                                                                                                               
    eqfile = open("string.txt")                                                                                                                                                
    gibberish = eqfile.read()                                                                                                                                                    
    eqfile.close()                                                                                                                                                               

    r = re.compile("[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}")                                                                                                                                      
    print r.findall(gibberish)
```

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answers guys! I guess I should have been more specific. I need to find the lowercase letter that is surrounded by three uppercase letters that are exactly the same, such as in my example `ZZZaZZZ`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are *so* close! Read about the `.group`* methods of [MatchObjects](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects). For example, if your script ended with

```
r = re.compile("[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}")
print r.match(gibberish).group(1)
```

then you'd capture the desired character inside the first group.

To address the new constraint of matching repeated letters, you can use backreferences:

```
r = re.compile(r'([A-Z])\1{2}(?P<middle>[a-z])\1{3}')
m = r.match(gibberish)
if m is not None:
    print m.group('middle')
```

That reads like:

1. Match a letter A-Z and remember it.
2. Match two occurrences of the first letter found.
3. Match your lowercase letter and store it in the group named `middle`.
4. Match three more consecutive instances of the first letter found.
5. If a match was found, print the value of the `middle` group.

Comment: This will fail to match both lower case letters in `"AAAbAAAbAAA"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
r = re.compile("(?<=[A-Z]{3})[a-z](?=[A-Z]{3})")
```

`(?<=...)` indicates a positive lookbehind and `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead.

[module re](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

> #### `(?=...)`
>
> Matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, `Isaac (?=Asimov)` will match `'Isaac '` only if it’s followed by `'Asimov'`.
>
> #### `(?<=...)`
>
> Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position.

Comment: +1, but I don't think you need both the lookahead and lookbehind. Either one on it's own should work with the other being a normal match

Comment: @gnibbler, True, but this way if you do a `findall` or `finditer` you just get back a list without having to do a comprehension.

Comment: `(?<=[A-Z]{3})([a-z])(?:[A-Z]{3})` does that too

Comment: @MikeSamuel Your solution is working the best so far, but I guess I should have been more specific. The uppercase letters need to be exactly the same such as the example I used above `ZZZaZZZ`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to capture the part of the string you are interested in with parentheses, and then access it with `re.MatchObject#group`:

```
r = re.compile("[A-Z]{3}([a-z])[A-Z]{3}")                                                                                                                                      
m = r.match(gibberish)
if m:
   print "Match! Middle letter was " + m.group(1)           
else:
   print "No match."
```

Comment: This will fail to match both lower case letters in `"AAAbAAAbAAA"`.