# How to use multiple 'if' statements nested inside an enumerator?

Tags: python

I have a massive string of letters all jumbled up, 1.2k lines long.
I'm trying to find a lowercase letter that has EXACTLY three capital letters on either side of it.

This is what I have so far

```
def scramble(sentence):
    try:
        for i,v in enumerate(sentence):
            if v.islower():
                if sentence[i-4].islower() and sentence[i+4].islower():
    ....
    ....
    except IndexError:
        print() #Trying to deal with the problem of reaching the end of the list


#This section is checking if 
the fourth letters before 
and after i are lowercase to ensure the central lower case letter has
exactly three upper case letters around it
```

But now I am stuck with the next step. What I would like to achieve is create a `for-loop` in range of `(-3,4)` and check that each of these letters is uppercase. If in fact there are three uppercase letters either side of the lowercase letter then print this out.

For example

```
for j in range(-3,4):
    if j != 0:
        #Some code to check if the letters in this range are uppercase
        #if j != 0 is there because we already know it is lowercase
        #because of the previous if v.islower(): statement.
```

If this doesn't make sense, this would be an example output if the code worked as expected

```
scramble("abcdEFGhIJKlmnop")
```

OUTPUT

```
EFGhIJK
```

One lowercase letter with three uppercase letters either side of it.

Comment: Why not use a regular expression?

Comment: Wow, people are still playing the Python Challenge? Cool beans, and sorry that the forums have since been overrun by spam bots.

Comment: I just found it so thought I would have a go @MartijnPieters and yeah the forums are no good unfortunately

Comment: What do you mean by use a regular expression @jsfan

Comment: something like `[A-Z]{3}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{3}`

Comment: Do not use loop in this case, instead use `regex`. It will be much more efficient. Solution to similar problem is available at: [Find a lowercase letter surronded by three uppercase letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10423385/find-a-lowercase-letter-surronded-by-three-uppercase-letters)

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Wow, regular expressions made this crazy easy ... Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it "Pythonically" without
regular expressions:

```
s = 'abcdEFGhIJKlmnop'

words = [s[i:i+7] for i in range(len(s) - 7) if s[i:i+3].isupper() and s[i+3].islower() and s[i+4:i+7].isupper()]
print(words)
```

And the output is:

```
['EFGhIJK']
```

And here is a way to do it *with* regular expressions,
which is, well, also Pythonic :-)

```
import re
words = re.findall(r'[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}', s)
```

Comment: I have never seen regular expressions before so they don't make sense to me sorry but I'm sure others will find it helpful

Comment: @Liam Regexen should be a tool in every programmer's toolkit. You don't have to use them all the time, but every once in a while they're the exact right solution. Go learn them.

Comment: @LiamEmery: Regular expressions (aka regex) are very good at finding certain kinds of pattern so it's a Good Idea to get some familiarity with regex. Many programming languages provide regular expression facilities, and the core syntax of regex does't change much from one language to the next, so once you know regex in Python you will find it easy to use regex in other languages too.

Comment: Your 1st code snippet will also find lowercase letters that have more than 3 uppercase letters on either side, but the OP wants EXACTLY 3 uppercase letters on either side.

Comment: very Pythonic, makes my solution seem obtuse and bloated :) always forgetting how concise list operations are in python

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think "Pythonic" means codegolf-ic

Answer (score 1):

if you can't use regular expression

maybe this for loop can do the trick

```
if v.islower():
    if sentence[i-4].islower() and sentence[i+4].islower():
         for k in range(1,4):
            if sentence[i-k].islower() or sentence[i+k].islower():
                break
            if k == 3:
               return i
```

Comment: Nice. Instead of `if k == 3:` you could use an `else` clause on the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

regex is probably the easiest, using a modified version of @Israel Unterman's answer to account for the outside edges and non-upper surroundings the full regex might be:

```
s = 'abcdEFGhIJKlmnopABCdEFGGIddFFansTBDgRRQ'

import re
words = re.findall(r'(?:^|[^A-Z])([A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3})(?:[^A-Z]|$)', s)

# words is ['EFGhIJK', 'TBDgRRQ']
```

using `(?:.)` groups keeps the search for beginning of line or non-upper from being included in match groups, leaving only the desired tokens in the result list.  This should account for all conditions listed by OP.

*(removed all my prior code as it was generally *bad*)*